# R Shiny: How to use conditions within main server function to call different module UI/server functions?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use if/then construct in main server function to determine which, out of a choice of two, modules to call, depending on user input.  One choice uses an add/remove action button module to call another module, the other choice calls a different module not using the add/remove button module.  Calling the module using add/ remove module is easy enough, as I am passing the UI to call as one of the parameters in the call to the add/remove button module, but I am not sure how to properly insertUI() in the server function after callModule().  So in my example (as simple as I could think to make it), the UI starts with a textInput() box, which defaults to 1.  I have a "first" module, which just prepends the userInput() data to letters a,b,c d in selectInput() box.  The "second"  module prepends "Not 1" to a,b,c,d in selectInput() box.  I use observeEvent({}) such that if user does nothing (textInput() stays at 1), then "first" module is called.  If the user changes textInput() to anything at all other than default 1, "second" module is called.  What I am not clear on is how to call the UI for the second module.  I have a uiOutput("dummy") as a placeholder in the ui() function.  However, my example does not work as described above, because it does not ever successfully call "second" module if the user changes the testInput() default value.  Code below, thanks!

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "first")) }

firstServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {
    ns = session$ns

    output$first <- renderUI({
        selectInput(ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0(isolate(a()), letters[1:4]))
    })

    return(reactive({ c(paste0(input$select), paste0(input$select)) }))
}
removeFirstUI <- function(id) {
    removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "first")))
}

secondUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "second")) }

secondServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {
    ns = session$ns

    output$second <- renderUI({
        selectInput(ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0("Not 1", letters[1:4]))
    })

    return(reactive({ c(paste0(input$select), paste0(input$select)) }))
}

removeSecondUI <- function(id) {
    removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "second")))
}

addRmBtnUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    tags$div(
    actionButton(inputId = ns('insertParamBtn'), label = "Add"),
    actionButton(ns('removeParamBtn'), label = "Remove"),
    hr(),
    tags$div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

addRmBtnServer <- function(input, output, session, moduleToReplicate, ...) {
    ns = session$ns

    params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0, a = list())

    observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
        params$btn <- params$btn + 1

        params$a[[params$btn]] <- callModule(moduleToReplicate$server, id = params$btn, ...)
        insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = moduleToReplicate$ui(ns(params$btn))
    )
    })

    observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
        moduleToReplicate$remover(ns(params$btn))
        params$btn <- params$btn - 1
    })

    return(params)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  addRmBtnUI("addRm"),
  textInput("a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE),
  uiOutput("dummy")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    a <- reactive({ input$a })
    comp <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(a(), {
        if (input$a == 1) {
            comp <- callModule(
            addRmBtnServer, id = "addRm",
            moduleToReplicate = list(
            ui = firstUI,
            server = firstServer,
            remover = removeFirstUI
            ),
            a = a
            )
        } else {
            comp <- callModule(
            secondServer, id = 0,
            a = a
            )
        }
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)

    output$text <- renderPrint({
        if (!(is.null(comp$btn))) {
            if (comp$btn > 0) {
            paste(
            comp$a[[comp$btn]](),
            sep = "     "
            )
            }
            } else { paste0("") }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You are not using the function `secondUI` anywhere.

Comment: That is my question.  How do I call the "second UI from within the conditional statement in the main server function?  I tried using renderUI() in the if section of server, but got the old familiar reactive variables misuse error

Comment: `secondUI(0)` should work.

Comment: OK, more specifically, this works:             output$dummy <- renderUI({ secondUI(0) })

Comment: I put that in the else{} section of conditional, and it works.  Thanks again, Gregor!